# Fix regex pattern in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this regex pattern `(\[|)(\w\w \d*)(\; |\*|\s|]?, )((\"(\w)\"|\((.\w)\))|)(\]|)|(\[\w\w \d\])` to match the below string:

```
Hp 0; Ks 1; Ks 2
```

I have tested this pattern in `https://regex101.com/`, and everything works fine, complete string is matched `Hp 0; Ks 1; Ks 2`
. But the same pattern in Visual Studio (.Net Framework) match just `Hp 0; Ks 1;`.

Can anyone help me where is the problem ?

I have written this code in VS:

```
 StringBuilder matchedSignalbegriff = new StringBuilder();

            var pattern = "(\\[|)(\\w\\w \\d*)(\\; |\\*|\\s|]?, )((\"(\\w)\"|\\((.\\w)\\))|)(\\]|)|(\\[\\w\\w \\d\\])";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

            foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(stringToTest))
            {
                matchedSignalbegriff.Append(match);
            }
```

Comment: You'll be a lot happier writing verbatim string literals (i.e.  literals prefaced with a `@`) when doing Regexes. Something like `var pattern = @"(\[|)(\w\w` etc. In all likelihood, you have a misplaced escape character if it works in a tool and not in your code

Comment: Apart from not using a verbatim string as @Flydog57 suggests, is there a reason why your pattern is so complicated? What other input variations are you trying to match?

Comment: Even if i use your pattern in regex101.com, *Hp 0;* and *Ks 1;* are two separate matches. To match the whole string *Hp 0; Ks 1; Ks 2*, you could use `Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(\[|)((\w\w \d*)((\; )?|\*|\s|]?, ))*((\""(\w)\""|\((.\w)\))|)(\]|)|(\[\w\w \d\])");`

Comment: @PeterE it looks complicated, because this is just one of 200 matches! This pattern match 200 different strings =)

Comment: @johnmoarr thanks, but again same result, just two parts are matched!

Comment: @DevOp maybe then you have to describe what you want to achieve a bit more in detail. While using the regex I provided, the whole string you described is matched. You can check it out in [this .net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q5k4GJ).

Comment: @DevOp There are many permutations of this format (which, I suppose, is railway signals) but they should never deviate much from the form in your example, right? I would suggest to use the structure of the pattern mentioned in @TheFourthBird's answer - `\w{2} \d+(?:; \w{2} \d+)*` - and build your special cases around that, for example by adding `(?:optional)?` blocks. That will probably be more readable than what you are doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern does not match the whole string or all 3 parts on regex101, see https://regex101.com/r/2ldB6Z/1

That is because this part `(\; |\*|\s|]?, )` has to match at least one of the listed character(s) which is not present in `Hp 0; Ks 1; Ks 2`

Using a construct like `(\[|)` in your pattern makes it optional due to the `|` at the end.

To make the pattern match all 3 parts, you can add asserting the end of the string in the alternation in your pattern:

```
var pattern = @"(\[|)(\w\w \d*)(\; |\*|\s|]?, |$)((""(\w)""|\((.\w)\))|)(\]|)|(\[\w\w \d\])";
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5c%5b%7c%29%28%5cw%5cw+%5cd*%29%28%3b+%7c%5c*%7c%5cs%7c%5d%3f%2c+%7c%24%29%28%28%22%28%5cw%29%22%7c%5c%28%28.%5cw%29%5c%29%29%7c%29%28%5d%7c%29%7c%28%5c%5b%5cw%5cw+%5cd%5c%5d%29&i=Hp+0%3b+Ks+1%3b+Ks+2&o=m) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/FdA0NE)

As an alternative for a more basic pattern to match the example string:

```
\w\w \d+(?:; \w\w \d+)*
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6lZn2F/1)